# Azure devops: Monorepo trigger

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a mono-repo with the below structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── azure-pipelines.yml
├── common.py
├── sample-job1
|── azure-pipelines-sample-job1.yml
│   └── entry-point1.py
└── sample-job2
    |── azure-pipelines-sample-job2.yml
    └── entry-point2.py
```

The entry-point1.py and entry-point2.py have common functions written in common.py.

- If I make changes to common.py : azure-pipelines get triggered
- If I make changes to entry-point1.py : azure-pipelines-sample-job1
  get triggered
- If I make changes to entry-point2.py : azure-pipelines-sample-job2
  get triggered

What I would like to have in addtion is:

- if I make changes to common.py (only if this file is modified), I
  want the other 2 pipelines to be triggered
  azure-pipelines-sample-job1.yml, azure-pipelines-sample-job2.yml in
  addition to the existing logic to trigger azure-pipelines.yml

This is because entry-point1.py and entry-point2.py calls common.py so a rebuild of the code is necessary every time common.py is changed.

How do I add this trigger?

Below is the current triggers I have :

#azure-pipelines.yml

```
# Build numbering format
name: $(BuildID)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - feat/*
  paths:
    exclude:
      - 'sample-job1/*'
      - 'sample-job2/*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello from '/' root folder."
```

#azure-pipelines-sample-job1.yml

```
# Build numbering format
name: $(BuildID)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - feat/*
  paths:
    include:
      - 'sample-job1/*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello from 'sample1'"
```

#azure-pipelines-sample-job2.yml

```
# Build numbering format
name: $(BuildID)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - feat/*
  paths:
    include:
      - 'sample-job2/*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello from 'sample2'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger *azure-pipelines-sample-job1.yml* and *azure-pipelines-sample-job2.yml* when file “*common.py*” is modified, just add its path to the trigger paths:

**azure-pipelines-sample-job1.yml**

```
# Build numbering format
name: $(BuildID)
 
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - feat/*
  paths:
    include:
      - 'sample-job1/*'
      - 'common.py'
 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
 
steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello from 'sample1'"
```

**azure-pipelines-sample-job2.yml**

```
# Build numbering format
name: $(BuildID)
 
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - feat/*
  paths:
    include:
      - 'sample-job2/*'
      - 'common.py'
 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
 
steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello from 'sample2'"
```

See: [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) for details.